# Updating database with values from textboxes 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

Simply i want ...if textbox1.text =S1, S2 then on button click event the S1 and S2 column value of Table in MSSql2005 database will be updated with the value "b" where date=1/3/2012

But the update is not working...

My MSSQL2005 Database structure :

```
id    date        S1    S2    S3

1     1/3/2012    b     b     NULL
```

Comment: uh, please clarify your question in the form of. `I'm trying to ______ but I can't seem to get it to ________. How can I achieve ________?`

Comment: Simply i want ...if textbox1.text =S1, S2 then on button click event the S1 and S2 column value of Table in MSSql2005 database will be updated with the value "b" where date=1/3/2012

Comment: @user1165438: Breakdown your code, try to solve your problems portion by portion. Now edit your code which part you want to focus on delete other parts, then if required post that part. State the difficulties you faced, the final output you want

Comment: in simple my problem are mentioned above

Comment: provide the code you have written so far. its hard to imagine the situation by ourselves..

Comment: You mean If TextBox1.Text= S1 AndAlso TextBox1.Text= s2 then update the s1 and s2 columns with the value "b". Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you 
**1**: To use parameterized queries 
 that is change a statement like
     dim query as string ="Select * from tbl where id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
To

```
dim query as string ="select * from tbl where id=@par"
dim cmd as new SqlCommand(query,conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("par",TextBox.Text)
```

This will avoid sql injection attach & it will reduce typing errors

**2**: Test your code portion by portion, so that you'll easily identify the problematic part.
and possibly you can seek help then.

**3**: Test your connection

**4**: Use break points and debugging options

I believe the best solution comes from the owner of the problem

Comment: I would add that you should do some sort of validation to the data from the textbox before you add it as a parameter to make sure it is not garbage data.